# Xrandr error when using using 2560x1440 monitor

Tags: xorg, 14.04, resolution, xrandr, intel-hd

I have an 2560x1440 monitor on an Intel HD graphics adapter. Since Intel HD cannot by default drive a display higher than 1920x1200, I used in Ubuntu 12.04 the following trick (derived from https://plus.google.com/+LinusTorvalds/posts/HQsCY7ErAL4):

```
xrandr --newmode "2560x1440"  222.52  2560 2720 2992 3424  1440 1441 1444 1477  -HSync +Vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI1 2560x1440
xrandr --output HDMI1 --mode 2560x1440
```

The modeline was found using

```
gtf 2560 1440 44
```

In Ubuntu 14.04 this does not work anymore: When trying to switch to the 2560x1440 mode I get

```
xrandr: Configure crtc 0 failed
```

Corresponding Xorg.log entries:

```
[  1067.430] (II) intel(0): switch to mode 2560x1440@40.0 on HDMI1 using pipe 0, position (0, 0), rotation normal, reflection none
[  1067.824] (EE) intel(0): failed to set mode: Invalid argument
[  1067.874] (II) intel(0): switch to mode 1920x1200@60.0 on HDMI1 using pipe 0, position (0, 0), rotation normal, reflection none
```

Any ideas how to get around this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you are using DVI or HDMI to connect (my machine reports both as HDMI in `xrandr`), but it seems that Intel HD graphics is limited to DVI single-link. As you noted, the highest it will report is 1900x1200@60Hz.

As far as I can tell, current Intel HD graphics do not support DVI dual-link.

However, it may be possible to enable 2560x1440@30Hz over DVI single-link if you're willing to take the hit on refresh rate.

**Source**: found most of the DVI information in an [Arch Linux forum post](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1402462#p1402462) and tested the alternate setting on my 2560x1440 monitor with Xubuntu 15.04. Setting it to 30Hz fixed the issue for me.