# External monitor's resolution too small with 14.04 via HDMI

Tags: 14.04, hdmi, external-monitor

My DELL 27inch monitor should be capable of 2560x1440 resolution. I've confirmed with Ubuntu 12.04 NVIDIA with DVI connection. Now on 14.04 `Intel® HD 4600` with HDMI, the maximum resolution I see is only `1920x1080`.

```
$ xrandr
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+   60.0     50.0     59.9     24.0     24.0  
   1920x1080i     60.1     50.0     60.0  
   1600x1200      60.0
```

Among many similar issues on askubuntu.com, I saw [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/462122/xrandr-error-when-using-using-2560x1440-monitor) gives a command set that seems kind of promising, but after `xrandr --output HDMI1 --mode 2560x1440`, the OS' display setting tool says the display got 2560x1440 (that's what I want) but the DELL monitor got blacked-off and stated:

```
Current input timing is not supported by the monitor display. Please change your input timing to 1920x1080@60Hz or any other monitor listed timing as per the monitor spec.
```

How can I get `2560x1440` on my external DELL monitor?